# Realtime microphone input to output on iOS with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, microphone

I have the following issue, and I have found a few topics here talking about it but none of these is actually answering my question.

I'm pretty new with iOS development, I searched the apple documentation but didn't found anything useful

I need to get the audio Sample/Buffer/Stream from the headphone microphone, in a manipulable variable or something like that. Then push it back to the headphones. That I can hear my voice when I'm talking.

I found things about AVFoundation but nothing more.

I know it’s possible to do that but I did not find how to

Can anybody help me further ?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the language you are looking for is swift,so you might can finding something useful on [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio),even this project was deprecated at June 13,2016.
You might want to check the example which called `PassThrough` in this project,this example has the function "Hearing the voice while talking",and this project was written with swift.
Wish could help.